# In MVC what does the httpOnlyCookies attribute actually do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl

I'm confused as to what this setting actually does.

According to MSDN, "Gets or sets a value indicating whether the support for the browser's HttpOnly cookie is enabled."

But I'm struggling to understand what this actually means.

The problem I am having is that in my MVC application, the session cookie is not being sent with the secure flag. I've put the `RequireSSL="True"` attribute in both forms and cookies sections of the web config, but the session ID cookie is still not sent under SSL. I was wondering if this other attribute was connected with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've implemented `requireSSL="true"`, your cookies should only be transmitted over the HTTPS protocol. Nothing more should be required for that. The HttpOnly flag tells the browser that the cookie should only be accessed by the server -- not by any client-side script. This prevents certain XSS attacks in modern browsers that respect this flag (should be pretty much all at this point).